# Moment.js changes locale to 'en' after ssr in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, momentjs, svelte, sveltekit

Moment.js is updating its locale to 'en' after ssr is done. So the dates display is right for a second, but then it changes to default.

routes/layout.svelte

```
<script>
    import moment from 'moment';
    moment.locale('ru');
</script>
```

I also tried

```html
<script>
    onMount(() => moment.locale('ru'));
</script>
```

after @depperm comment, I created a helper function, that uses store and vanilla JS

lib/helpers/date.ts

```
import { locale } from "$lib/store/locale"

let l = 'ru-RU';
locale.subscribe((loc) => l = loc);

export function date(date: Date, options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions): string {
    return date.toLocaleDateString(l, options ??  { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
}
```

lib/store/locale.ts

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const locale = writable<string>('ru-RU');
```

but it does not seem to me as a good solution

Comment: momentjs isn't really supported anymore [why you shouldn't use momentjs](https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js), [you probably don't need momentjs anymore](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore), and [4 alternatives to international dates](https://blog.logrocket.com/4-alternatives-to-moment-js-for-internationalizing-dates/)

Answer (score 0):

Use date-fns. It's svelte compatible and has very good documentation.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I agree that moment should not be used anymore, but in legacy projects it might be hard to get rid of it.